# How can I share the folder var/www on my emulated Ubuntu virtual machine with the hosting OS?

Tags: vmware

How can I share the folder var/www on my emulated Ubuntu virtual machine with the hosting operating system ? (In this case OSX Leopard)

I'm using vmware, I've installed VMware Tools. I can drag and drop files in between the 2 os.

I just need this last step.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VMware (I'm assuming Fusion), go to your Ubuntu virtual machine Settings -> Sharing. Share the `/var/www` folder as read-write. You likely won't be able to select it from the dialog box so just type it with ⇧⌘G. That folder gets mounted under Ubuntu at `/mnt/hgfs/www`. In Ubuntu, make a symlink `/var/www` to `/mnt/hgfs/www`.

Comment: @fideli the link worked thanks. I still have one question, I've deleted a folder with the hosting OS and they changed color in the Ubuntu terminal but they are still there. What does that mean ?

Comment: I've actually rename one of them, but I cannot see the renamed one (just the old one is now red)

Comment: @Patrick Hmm, I'm not sure why it wouldn't update properly.

Comment: @fideli mhm ok, they modified files and folders just disappear from apache if I access the directory with my browser. I need to fix this, since I want to edit these files with an external editor from the hosting os

Comment: I've found out why. I was linking all files inside the folder instead of the parent folder. Obviously this didn't work..

Comment: Great, good to hear!