# Sharing Files between VM and Host OS

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine

I am trying to share files (about a 1GB of data) between my work computer and a VMWare guest OS on the same physical machine. The guest, as loaded from a snapshot, is by default in its own workgroup. The host is connected to the company domain network. I am afraid if I leave the workgroup/domain with either computer, I will screw something up. Both machines are running Windows 7 Enterprise.

How can I transfer the files to my VM?

Comment: Have you installed VMware tools? http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1035392

Also, possible dup: http://superuser.com/questions/206335/how-can-i-share-the-folder-var-www-on-my-emulated-ubuntu-virtual-machine-with-th. I would take a look there for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

define network interface as on the VM to NAT this way you can access and define the VM just like you have another station in the network ,side by side.